# What is the meaning of に匹敵する in this sentence

Tags: meaning

「数多ある父親らしからぬ時間が、今の父親たる私を父親たらしめんとしている！！」

「すなわち、この姿は我が娘が母親がほしいほしいと夜な夜なベッドで泣いていたひとしずくの涙に匹敵する！」

I read the last sentence as something like:

In other words, this look/appearence (女装している）is comparable to the tears of my daughter crying in her bed at night, begging for a mother.

This does not sound quite right to me and I'm not quite sure how to understand に匹敵 in this context.

Comment: I don't see any problem with your interpretation.

Comment: Maybe I'm silly but I don't get the comparison.

Answer (score -1):

Your translation itself seems reasonable to me. He is comparing someone's appearance with his daughter's tears. More context is needed because something very unusual seems to be happening here, but assuming he's doing 女装, maybe he's trying to say "my appearance may be outlandish but it's as beautiful/precious as my daughter's tears" or something like this.